# how to add decimal point to a long number according to indicated position in R

Tags: r

Hello I have for example the following data:

```r
datos = c(191659, 190213, 190270)

decimal <- function(x){
  a <- as.character(x)
  s = gsub('\\.','',a )
  fin = substr(s, nchar(s) - (3 - 1), nchar(s))
  inicio =  substr(s, 1,  nchar(s) - nchar(fin))
  rt = paste0(inicio,".",fin)
  return(as.numeric(rt ) )
}

decimal(datos[3])
```

Return: `19.027` **is there any way to prevent the zero from being removed?**

> The correct result should be `190.270`

Comment: Did you try `datos/1000`?

Comment: What happens is that in my original data the size of the characters are variable (`nchar(datos[3]) = 6` 6,5,4)  and I want to make it automatic, that is, I place decimals 3 characters to the right

Comment: How about `cat(sprintf("%6.3f", datos/1000))`?

Comment: If you  have `4456` (4 digits) and you do `4456/1000`, it works perfect.

Comment: @dcarlson tank you, sprintf("%6.3f", datos/1000)